# Show apps listed under "More Apps" by default for UIActivityViewController instead of requiring tap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

The UIActivityViewController offers a "More Apps" button which shows other apps for sharing. Screenshot #1 shows the UIActivityViewController with the "More Apps" button.

Screenshot #2 shows the UIActivityViewController after tapping "More Apps" with all the supporting apps listed.

Is it possible to show by default screenshot #2, i.e., list all the apps that support sharing? We expect most users to tap "More Apps" and would like to save them one tap.

**Screenshot #1**

[image: screenshot]

**Screenshot #2**

[image: screenshot]